# Prevent gcc using the leave instruction

Tags: c, gcc

By disassembling some C code I found out that gcc is using the `leave` instruction instead of

```
mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
```

I know both versions are completely equivalent but for debugging purposes with gdb I would like to change it. I couldn't find any information regarding this topic so any hint would help.

Comment: You will have to change `gcc` and recompile it. I don't think you want to do it. Alternatively you can make gcc to emit the assembly for you, change the opcodes manually and assemble.

Comment: _"but for debugging purposes with gdb I would like to change it."_ To achieve what? There might be a solution, but you should give the full picture.

Comment: @black The only thing that can justify it is a HW bug, incorrectly implementing some opcodes..

Comment: @edmz You can grep easier if you only have to look for one pattern.